# good book on Jquery and it's compatibility with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Any recommendations?

I have used Jquery already but I would like to really delve into it and find out how I can use it with asp.net, specifically instead of updatepanel and ajax toolkit.

I use asp.net forms.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery/Javascript works on the client site, so it's server side language agnostic. I have not done a whole lot of .NET coding, but If I wanted to use jQuery with my .NET app, I would use MVC more instead of Webforms and build all the html/css/js by hand.

[This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847192505) is a good book I would recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding jQuery, I found [jQuery in Action](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/28/jquery-and-microsoft.aspx) very useful. It is not just as exciting as the [bungee book on prototype](http://www.thebungeebook.net/2007/12/22/the-book-is-shipping/), but it is very pragmatic, just as the library is. Prototype is so clever and jQuery is so powerful.

Skimming the book and browsing examples is enough to get you started, but be sure to read also the appendix on advanced JavaScript because it is where you will learn what language features have been leveraged to create the library.

Regarding jQuery and ASP.NET, two things are worth noticing.

1) [Microsoft is supporting jQuery as is](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/28/jquery-and-microsoft.aspx) in visual studio. No forks, no embrace and extend, just clean support, so you will be able to learn all you need in a non specific book.

2) developing with jQuery is orthogonal to ASP.NET. You will use Visual Studio as a powerful text editor without thinking in terms of ASP.NET components and code behind. There is no code behind in an interactive web application built with jQuery.
If you need to do something on the server, you will build an aspx page processing parameters and returning raw data without user interface and call it with ajax. The ideal format is [JSON](http://www.json.org/).

I would not choose a book particularly targeted to jQuery and ASP.NET without good reason, especially at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how advanced you already are with jQuery, [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626219) book may be a good one. It is broader in scope than just the jQuery library itself, so the jQuery coverage may not be as thorough as you would like. It does target .net though, and also discusses other relevant libraries such as the Telerik asp.net ajax control library.

Comment: that's what i mean. in my opinion, all these ajax libs would be redundant if you use jquery. correct me if i am wrong, though. being a simplicity person, i would like to use one ajax lib and use it well. for instance, i wouldn't mix up updatepanel with jquery ajax calls. i am already using jquery in my asp.net app, and as many here noted it language agnostic. for example, how do i achieve updatepanel funcionality with jquery....that type of thing. MS supports jquery because they basically have to these days - with it being a standard in client side dev.

Comment: While I agree in principle that you might be able to make all the other ajax libraries redundant just by rolling your own controls with jQuery, I'm not sure you would want to take the time and effort to do so. I think a strength of Dino's book is the comparing/contrasting of different approaches to ajax on the asp.net platform, including using other libraries and the shortcomings of controls like the updatepanel. That said, some of the material may be outdated soon and you can't go wrong pairing it with a good platform agnostic ajax (like Ajax in Action) or jQuery (if you're set on it) book.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read [this book](http://amzn.com/B0036V7H4M) but it does seem to cover what you are looking for, it only seems to be available as an ebook though.

I plan to get [this](http://amzn.com/0470643188) book when it comes out, its MVC 2 instead of webforms but from what I have read MVC2 uses jQuery out of the box.

For a general jquery book, I like [this](http://amzn.com/1935182323) one, Its not out yet but I've seen some chapters from the early access program and it looks good, one of the authors is on the jQuery core team so the code is solid and they have been updating the book to match the latest 1.4 release (I'm not sure about 1.4.1 and 1.4.2)

One point I would make about using jQuery with asp.net is the way asp.net up until 3.5 renders client id tags, its a pain to work with and you end up doing selectors by regular expression ( "id$=myTextBox" ) or by class, both of which are slower than selecting by id.
In asp.net 4 you have more control over how the ids are rendered so that is better, but you have most control with MVC.

HTH